# MySQL check if MAX value has duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm running contests on my website. Every contest could have multiple entries. I want to retrieve if only the MAX value of votes has a duplicate.

The table is as follows:

```
contest_id    entry_id    votes
1             1           50
1             2           34
1             3           50
2             4           20
2             5           55
3             6           53
```

I just need the query to show me that contest 1 has a duplicate MAX value without additional information.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
SELECT MAX(votes) from contest group by contest_id having count(votes) > 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.contest_ID
FROM    contest a
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT contest_id, MAX(votes) totalVotes
          FROM contest
          GROUP BY contest_id
        ) b ON a.contest_ID = b.contest_ID AND
               a.votes = b.totalvotes
GROUP BY a.contest_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e4d1/8)

Answer (score 5):

This finds the max votes value per contest and counts the entries with that number of votes.
It then displays contest with more than one hit.

```
SELECT contest_id
FROM contests
WHERE votes=(
  SELECT MAX(votes) FROM contests c WHERE c.contest_id=contests.contest_id
)
GROUP BY contest_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcf97/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by first selecting the maximum number of votes for each contest ID in a subquery, and then joining against the results ([demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd5f2/1)):

```
SELECT contest_id, votes
FROM contest
  JOIN (
    SELECT contest_id, MAX(votes) AS votes
    FROM contest GROUP BY contest_id
  ) AS foo USING (contest_id, votes)
GROUP BY contest_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The nice thing about doing it like this is that it's an independent subquery, so MySQL only needs to rub it once.

Ps. Yes, this is basically identical to JW's answer, but I figured I'd leave it up anyway to show the slightly different syntax I used for the join.